# Merge conflicts don't appear unless merge request is opened

Tags: gitlab

In the GitLab "Merge requests" list, I can not see which items have merge conflicts unless I open merge request.
When merge request opened then icon of merge conflict appears in merge request list near that merge request that was opened.

Is there are way automatically update merge requests state?

Because it is really annoying when you can not see that merge request could no longer be merged unless you go through the list opening each merge request from time to time just to trigger merge conflict check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and setup a [Merge Request pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html) which can run anytime you create or update a merge request.

That pipeline could make an [`GET /merge_requests` API call](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#merge-requests-list-response-notes), with  `with_merge_status_recheck` parameter to `true`, in order to force the MR status to be refreshed.

Comment: The problem is that I do not update merge request and when merge request is created it has no conflicts. But during the development, someone on different branch makes changes to same file and merges those changes to master. Which results in my branch no longer be able to be merged without conflicts. However I am not notified in any way about that until I open my merge request from the list to view it. Then status changes. But when there is a lot of merge request on the list it is really not convenient to go open each item in the list just to force status re-check...

Comment: @AndriusOlišauskas OK. That same pipeline could be then configured to run *also* when the target branch (master here) is updated.